# ASP.Net forms authentication - go to login page on timeout

Tags: asp.net, timeout, forms-authentication

is it possible to redirect to login page when timeout occurs without waiting for the user to click on anything first?
Right now, when timeout occurs, the page user was on still displays but as soon as user clicks on anything it goes to login page.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check on the client side if the session has expired. The easiest way is to simply start a countdown (as long as the timeout) using javascript when the page has been loaded. When it expires, send the user to the login page. Or maybe better: just let the user know that the session has expired, because maybe he wouldn't be too happy if you just send him somewhere. Although my online banking software does exactly that, but for security reasons, of course.

Here's a very simple example:  http://jsfiddle.net/39Sj6/1/

```
function sessionHasExpired(){
    if(confirm("Your session has expired. Do you want to go to the login page")){
        window.location = "http://google.com/?q=login";   
    }
}

var sessionTimeInMilliseconds = 1000*60*5; // here: 5 minutes
setTimeout(sessionHasExpired, sessionTimeInMilliseconds );
```

(In jsfiddle you won't be redirected to google as this is forbidden by jsfiddle, but in principle it would work)

​

Comment: Thanks Andre. This is an intranet app with some sesitive data displayed on some of the pages, so they won't mind if at timeout they are automatically logged out. Can you provide some sample code on how to achieve this? If I am using master pages, should the countdown script be on the master page?

Comment: I've accidentally added the example to Mark's answer instead of mine. I've added the example to this answer, too. If you don't want to ask the user whether to leave the page or not, don't use the confirm() construct, simply set window.location instead. The script can be added to the master page if it counts for every page, yes. Not that if you're doing ajax calls you should reset the timeout after each ajax call.

Comment: Thanks again Andre. A couple of things: when I click on OK and go to login page, I can click browser's back button, go to where I was and continue doing what I was doing. Timeout has occurred but my session is still alive. Also, if I put the script on my master page, does the timer start from 0 when I go from page to page or does it contimue where it left off?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you could either poll the session state via Javascript timer and an ajax call to check the Server session state, then redirect to the login page, or, you could set a set a timer to a specified time limit (20 min or session timeout) and then redirect to login page.

Comment: If you poll the server, the session will get refreshed. It's like opening the fridge door to see if the light really goes out.

Comment: I didn't realize a GET would refresh the session, that wouldn't work then.  Might be a good alternative to the timeout though, kind of like a Session defibrillator. :)

Comment: Absolutely - "don't you die on my, damn session!" :-)

Comment: @AndreLoker Don't you post an answer briefing this and/or provide links so that folks like me would benefit from it. Thanks.